# Python extension in c

Tags: python, c

I have an issue while calling Python from C.

**cprogrem.c**

```c
  pyinitialize();
  PyObject *pName = PyString_FromString("python");
  PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
  pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "ExrtactDIEinfo");
  pReturn = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc,NULL); // my python function has no arguments
```

**python.py**

```py
def ExrtactDIEinfo():
      print "ExtractDIEinfo1" # this one is printed
      # when my c function try to execute this line it gets error means python can understand this path but when calling from cit gives error
      from elftools.elf.elffile import ELFFile # cannot import from c but as a python it run well
      print "ExtractDIEinfo1" # it is not get print
```

Could anyone please tell me a solution?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Are you aware about `pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "ExrtactDIEinfo");`? `"ExrtactDIEinfo"` looks like a typo and probably should be `"ExtractDIEinfo"`. (I wouldn't mention this but I remember that I once searched a half day for a link error until I recognized the signature in the C++ file had a slight difference to the signature in the header, and, (due to function overloading) there wasn't any other complaint than the said link error. Desperately staring at this helped me to solve it finally but this half day has burnt into my mind - a valuable experience...)